# virtual or type casting

Tags: c++, casting, event-handling, polymorphism

I have a question. I am trying to create the code to update my game but I have gotten into a "dilemma". I don't want to use virtual and the only reason for it is EVERYBODY i talked to (in forums, chats, friends) say that virtuals make the code really slow, so I did a research and found out that the lookup it does from vtable can decrease the performance by almost half. So, I use it for tasks that doesn't need to be updated every frame. Everything worked fine until I got to the update/render functions. Then I started thinking to find a workaround. Got an idea but first I would like to ask people who have knowledge on that one before implementing it.

My game engine is very event driven. I can send any kind of data using events in between subsystems (graphics, ui, scripting). So, I am thinking of sending an event "renderScene" every frame. It sounds great to me but there is a problem. The structure of the event handlers are not that great and I really don't want to improve this right now because it does a really decent job and my goal is to finish my game instead of fixing up the engine and never finish it (happened to me, so don't want to go back to it again).

My event handler have a function that registers events to functions (i call the handlers). But the problem with that function is, I need to do function bindings and stuff to register member functions. So, I found a workaround it - I create a static function and call the member function from it. This is how exactly a static function look like:

```
void GraphicsSubsystem::renderScene(Subsystem * subsystem, Event * event) {
   GraphicsSubsystem * graphics = static_cast<GraphicsSubsystem *>(subsystem);
   graphics->renderScene();
}

void ScriptingSubsystem::runLine(Subsystem * subsystem, Event * event) {
   ScriptingSubsystem * scripting = static_cast<ScriptingSubsystem *>(subsystem);
   Event1<String> * e = static_cast<Event1<String> *>(event);
   scripting->runLine(e->getArg());
}
```

There arguments are always the abstract subsystem class and the base event class. The **runLine** function I have no problem casting because I dont run a line of code on every frame. However, the **renderScene** function makes me a little bit uncomfortable.

tl;dr So, here is my question. Is static casting an object on every frame faster than calling a virtual function on every frame?

Comment: Don't be scared of using virtual methods. That's just premature optimisation.

Comment: I am going to try the event based rendering the scene because it fits my design more. You were right, I would worry about building the structure and then worry about performance. and the game is not going to be a huge MMO or anything, so I should worry about these kinda things. Thank you everybody!!

Answer (score 6):

Yes, a static cast is a quite fast operation. A static cast is static, i.e. all parameters are known at compile time and at runtime a pointer is modified by a constant.

However, you also shouldn't be over-pessimistic on virtual function calls. While they are slower than normal function calls, they are still very, very fast on many timescales, especially compared to the cost of rendering a scene. I can hardly imagine a game that is made slow by `O(1)` virtual function calls per frame. Make a clean design first, and worry about slowness when you observe a slow game and can profile to see where exactly it is slow.

Comment: +1 Renderscene will be many many times slower than virtual function call overhead.

Comment: The problem is that an object-oriented design using virtuals is nearly impossible to speed up after the fact, because the slowness is evenly spread through everything. To be truly fast, the design has to match the hardware for maximum speed right from the beginning. Static functions processing arrays of data with minimal redirection. Whole different design pattern.

Answer (score 3):

The general answer is it depends on the particular circumstances.

However, try to imagine what the runtime does on virtual function on invocation - it takes the this pointer, looks up the pointer of the function in the virtual method table and runs the function.

For me, it's unclear why this should be slower than your static casting.

If I were you, I would create a prototype code / stub using both methods and invoked it a million times and measured the performance.

Answer (score 3):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674982/performance-hit-from-c-style-casts) discusses the costs of a static cast, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667634/what-is-the-performance-cost-of-having-a-virtual-method-in-a-c-class) the costs of virtual dispatch. The latter, explaining that although the vtable lookup is not very expensive, the performance impact of lost optimisation and cache misses may be appreciable.

Hence your concerns are at least worth thinking about. (My initial thought was that surely the work done in (say) rendering the scene would be much more significant than the costs of calling the function.)

@Jiri's comment is surely right though, the only way to really know is to measure it - the effects we're talking about here are very specific to compiler/optimiser/CPU cleverness. It wouldn't take long to build the tests.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the features of virtual functions, just use them. They are there because they are useful.

If there is a simple and efficient way to implement this on your system, obviously the compiler implementors have already done so.

Trust your compiler!